# Javascript - Best way to encrypt data with password

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm creating a server which can store cookies on the web that will contain application settings. The server will accept any data, but I want to encrypt all the settings before storing them in a cookie and decrypt them when reading them out. So I can store very sensitive data like Account Usernames & Passwords in the cookies and the server cannot do anything with it.

My question is now: What is the best way to encrypt such data with a password in JavaScript on the client side? What is the most secure?

I need some code that I can embed into my site and use it from there.

Comment: [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssl)...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd recommend using AES encryption in your JavaScript code. See [Javascript AES encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793812/javascript-aes-encryption) for libraries and links. The trouble you'll have is picking a key that is only available on the client side. Perhaps you can prompt the user? Or hash together some client system information that's not sent to the server.

Comment: Ok, great! I think that's what I searched for ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could try a [Vernam Cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Vernam#The_Vernam_cipher) with the password.

Basically you use the password as the key and then XOR the string to encrypt with the password.  This can be reversed as well.

Here is a wikipedia page this type of encryption http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher

Example Code

```
function encrypt(key, value) {
  var result="";
  for(i=0;i<value.length;++i)
  {
    result+=String.fromCharCode(key[i % key.length]^value.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return result;
}

function decrypt()
{
 var result="";
  for(i=0;i<value.length;++i)
  {
    result+=String.fromCharCode(key[i % key.length]^value.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return result;
}
```

I haven't tested this but its probably close.  you will notice the encrypt and decrypt functions should be identical

Comment: Don't roll your own crypto. The proposed solution requires

1) Key which is as long as the value encrypted
2) Suffers from statistical attacks: if you encrypt more than one value with the same key, malicious party will likely be able to decrypt both values

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Misunderstood your question. Check out this question instead:

[What encryption algorithm is best for encrypting cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/606179/388916)

Comment: This is not exactly what OP was asking.

Comment: Ok, re-reading the OP's question a few times I admittedly misunderstood his question. I think my link to the similar, old question should deserve you removing your -1 though :)

Comment: I cannot hash the passwords. My app is built to not need an account, but it supports many API's like DropBox, FTP, SFTP and many other things. It's a development environment. So they'll need to enter some account information that is needed to access the APIs. I don't want that users of the app need a account to use it. They can save all their data in such a cookie. Later I'll make all the code open source, so many other people will host the app. And maybe the people want to host their own cookie servers, too. I don't want to store any userdata on my server. I'll be just a provider of the app.

Comment: Let's hope that person has a habit of checking in on his downvotes :3

Comment: @FlashFan: I've updated my answer :) Sorry for misunderstanding your question

Comment: @Codemonkey: I gave you a +1 for changing your answer the right way ;)