# Storing encrypted username/password for authentication on remote website without OAuth

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication

I'm building an web application that lets a user enter their credentials for Website-A, and granting my application permission to log in on their behalf. Website-A does not have an API, it does not support OAuth, etc. OAuth is not an option, and it appears most of the other questions based around this recommend OAuth.

Is the best way to do this to encrypt their passwords using any one of the popular encryption algorithms, store the key somewhere safe, and call it good? Their accounts will theoretically be read-only.

The stack uses PHP/MySQL but we're running Node.js with Request and Cheerio to handle the authentication, in some extreme cases we're actually using PhantomJS to render the site (when they are ajax heavy).

Thanks!

Comment: How long do you require your app to be able to continue accessing Website-A after the user provides her credentials to you? How long do Website-A authenticated sessions last, relative to that timeframe? Does your app *need* to reestablish terminated sessions *without user interaction*? AFAIK, a lot of personal financial management platforms (webapps that monitor one's financial transactions by logging in to one's banking websites, e.g. [Yodlee](http://www.yodlee.com/) etc) essentially do this, but do not retain credentials - they just pass them through to Website-A interactively.

Comment: Our app essentially polls Website-A listening for changes around the clock. So should the session expire, it will re-authenticate itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no surprise that AES CBC with strong padding is the best bet. You'll find a longer discussion here: [What encryption algorithm is best for encrypting cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606179/what-encryption-algorithm-is-best-for-encrypting-cookies)

Heck, you could even use the MySql built-in [AES_ENCRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt).

It's all about your key safety.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest to use encryption framework with good security record instead of "popular encryption algorithms"
2. definition of "somewhere safe" is rather vague, but I think if both you and your users are fine with it — it's ok.

Make sure that your users understand how you store their passwords so they are prepared to possible consequences.