# how to safe and encryte to protect datas in PHP, Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, encryption

I want to know how to safe and encryte to protect my cookie's datas in PHP and  Codeigniter

and i want to learn about what the most secure encryption method, nonation

thanks.. :) !

Comment: possible duplicate of [What encryption algorithm is best for encrypting cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606179/what-encryption-algorithm-is-best-for-encrypting-cookies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For encrypt the cookie in codeigniter make changes in the config.php file at

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
```

change this line to

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
```

Also set the encryption key at

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "Your_own_key";
```

**Please Note:**

It's worth noting that you shouldn't rely on storing sensitive data with the client, even encrypted. You're more secure to just store the session id (or for longer life, a user id and checksum) in the cookie and keep the sensitive information under your own control in a database (again, encrypted). Using SSL mitigates this issue but it's still not an ideal solution. Also, Cookies can be cleared which may pose problems